# Regex for finding string with more than 1 space but does not end with newline

Tags: regex

Regex gurus, please help me here:

I need a regex that finds more than one space which does not end in a newline.  For example consider the  text below:

```
Column 1       Column 2       Column 3        Column 4
Column 1       Column 2       Column 3        Column 4
```

Regex should match the spaces between Column X, where X = 1, 2 or 3, but should not match the space after Column 4.  Regex should also not match the single space between the word "Column" and its respective number.

I have tried `\s+^(\n)` but it is not working

Comment: What you need is a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: How about: `[ \t]+(?!\n)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj not the same question. The question you refer to is looking for any white space not consecutive.

Comment: you could easily modify the regexes to match two or more spaces.

Comment: @klaus `I need a regex that finds more than one space which does not end in a newline` What do you mean by this?

Comment: `Column X, where X = 1, 2 or 3, but should not match the space after Column 4` but there isn't a single horizontal space exists after to the col 4. Did you mean the `\n` exist next to the col4?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  It's not about the spaces themselves, but a sequence of spaces not ending with a newline. @AvinashRaj please remove this flag and I can answer it.

Comment: @OvedD i wondered, that why op fail to make a conversation with me. See his example, there isn't a horizontal space exits next to the column 4.

Comment: @OvedD According to your wish :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj, this is not a duplicate.  None of the answers in the post you've suggested as duplicate works in Notepad++.  Also, there could be 1 more spaces after column 4.  I do not want to match those, since they will end with a newline.

Comment: @anubhava, I am currently working in Notepad++.

Comment: @Wolph, your regex is matching white space between the word "Column" and its respective number e.g space in "Column 4".

Comment: @KlausNji: ah, didn't know you wanted to ignore those. In that case it's `{2,}` instead of `+` like this: `[ \t]{2,}(?!\n)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/ {2,}(?! *$)/gm
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eE5oX8/1)

**Explanation:**

- `{2,}` - matches 2 or more spaces
- `}(?! *$)` - is a negative lookahead to make sure to not to match when there or only 0 or more spaces before end of input
- `m` flag makes sure that every newline is matched by anchor `$` (used above in lookahead)

Comment: Perhaps add an explanation of the working parts rather than just a regex? *That* would merit an upvote

Comment: Question was put on hold as soon as I posted an answer. However I have added it now.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
\b(\s(?![\n\r])){2,}\b
```

It essentially says match:

- whole "words", hence the `\b` [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- with two or more spaces `\s` `{2,}`
- not followed by a return character, by using a negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?![\n\r])`